# Access query in SQL Server broken

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a UNION query that was working in a Microsoft Access environment. The error I am getting in SQL Server is: "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference". The query is in the below format:

```
SELECT tblA.ProjectID, 
       tblB.PersonnelID, 
       "TeamMember" AS ProjectRole
FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON (tblA.ProjectID = tblB.ProjectID) 
    AND (tblA.ProjectID = tblB.ProjectID) 
GROUP BY tblA.ProjectID, tblB.PersonnelID, "TeamMember"
HAVING ((Not (tblB.PersonnelID) Is Null) AND ((Sum(tblB.Hours))>0))
```

How to get this query working for SQL Server?

Comment: you do not need to do same condition `(tblA.ProjectID = tblB.ProjectID)` and there is no any issue in your query except Single Quote which `Marin Smith` have suggested...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Vishal. Issue is indeed different..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik `having` only applies to aggragate functions like sum, so i moved the `not null` thing into the `where`.also the quotes need to be singles. i have also put the join criteria in a single parenthesis. try this:

```
SELECT tblA.ProjectID, 
       tblB.PersonnelID, 
       'TeamMember' AS ProjectRole
  FROM tblA 
 INNER JOIN 
       tblB 
    ON (tblA.ProjectID = tblB.ProjectID
   AND  tblA.ProjectID = tblB.ProjectID) 
 where tblB.PersonnelID is not null
 GROUP BY 
       tblA.ProjectID
     , tblB.PersonnelID
     , 'TeamMember'
HAVING Sum(tblB.Hours) > 0
```